# How to open display settings in Windows 10(Pogrammatically, specifically using C#)?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-10, microsoft-metro

I'm trying to open/launch display in windows 10 using C#.

I have tried this:

```
Process.Start("explorer.exe", @"shell:::{BB06C0E4-D293-4f75-8A90-CB05B6477EEE}");
```

but it opening About (Information about the computer).

Any help?

Comment: SendKeys Windows key + E or R for the run dialog would be the shortest code. *open/launch display in windows* is very vague

Comment: Are you trying to run `control desk.cpl`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No need for GUID, The easiest way on *Windows 10* is

```
Process.Start("ms-settings:display");
```

Use this URI scheme *"ms-settings:"* to launch the Windows Settings app to specific settings pages. See [Launch the Windows Settings app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-settings-app).

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly. I wonder if it would work in other windows versions.

Comment: Works on windows 10 only.

Comment: @kennyzx Do you know what the windows 8 equivalent is?

Comment: In the link you provided, Microsoft states that the way to open the Settings app to the Display page is:

`bool result = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-settings:display"));`

FWIW, this works on Windows 11, whereas the `Process.Start()` method throws an exception.

Comment: Only as hint from my side; To use the launcher I need at least Target OS Win 10, https://stackoverflow.com/a/77714638/356726

Answer (score 1):

You are using the **wrong** GUID.  The one you are using is for showing **System**.

Try {C555438B-3C23-4769-A71F-B6D3D9B6053A} instead.

https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/3123-clsid-key-guid-shortcuts-list-windows-10-a.html

Comment: This would also work in Windows 7 (the GUID is the same).

Answer (score 1):

Open display settings in `Windows 7/8/8.1/10`. Also tested and works on Windows 11 (23H2)

```
Process.Start("Rundll32.exe","shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL desk.cpl");
```

Other elements of the control panel, see [List of Rundll32 Commands in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/77458-rundll32-commands-list-windows-10-a.html)

Answer (score -1):

The way to do this is to use the Shell32 object.  Add a reference to the COM Microsoft Shell Controls and Automation.  This will add Shell32.

Then

```
        var shell = new Shell32.Shell();
        shell.Explore(@"C:\");
```

This will open file explorer to the root of the C drive.

Notes:
    1. This call will block until the explorer exists.
    2. You need have [STAThread] or else you will get an impossible to interpret error.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question