# Can I somehow call the UWP launcher from a Windows Forms Application?

Tags: c#, winforms, uwp

I would like to open the Windows settings with the launcher. It is a one-liner in UWP. Docu: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-settings-app

```
bool result = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-settings:privacy-webcam"));
```

How can I do this from a Windows Form application?

An answer of [How to open display settings in Windows 10(Pogrammatically, specifically using C#)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51274892/356726) points out to use `Process`, but this only seems to work under Win10, not with Win11 anymore.: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51276033/356726

```
Process.Start("ms-settings:display");
```

The `RunDLL` solution seems to be a workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58260947/356726

But any chance to use the launcher in Win Forms?

Comment: Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync method can be called in desktop apps. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-enhance

Comment: Good comment, just for the record. I need at least target platform 10..0.17763 in the project file for it to compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credits to *emoacht*, as pointed out in the comment:

Launch settings app: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-settings-app

Call Windows Runtime APIs in desktop apps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-enhance

For me it requires at least target OS version Windows 10:

[image: Win OS 10]

Comment: Glad you've made it. You could accept your answer which will help others who are facing the same issue.

Comment: Sure, only last time the grace period before accepting own answers was still active.